# Compare two different multidimentional arrays and highlight the changes

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am creating a log file in which I want to show the old entry and the updated entry both together, but along those I also want to highlight the changes in the new entry like it's being done in stackoverflow when we edit the question they highlight the edited part.

As you can see there is a difference in the description and there are many other indexes, I am just showing some of them.

I have two different arrays that look like this:

new entry

```
   Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (

            [business_logo] => 31190_photo.jpg
            [business] => Sms Factory Powered By Bds Technologies Pvt Ltd
            [b_discription] => We smsfactory are world's leading SMS messaging provider offering remarakable and reliable SMS Text and Voice messaging globally through almost all-networks of mobile phones successfully. You may contact-us anytime for making any query. Our Services are very useful economically as well as eco-friendly,
            [mod_date] => 1467736200
        )

)
```

old entry

```
  Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [business_logo] => 31190_photo.jpg
            [business] => Sms Factory Powered By Bds Technologies Pvt Ltd
            [b_discription] => We smsfactory are world's leading SMS messaging provider offering remarakable and reliable SMS Text and Voice messaging globally through almost all-networks of mobile phones successfully. You may contact-us anytime for making any query. Our Services are very useful economically as well as eco-friendly, which enables you to send simultaneous bulk sms to your targeted Customers, Regular-Customers, Buyers, Shoppers, Fans, Regular-shoppers, Clients, Clientele, Members, Managers, Supervisors, Fieldworkers, Graduates, Post graduates, Technicians, Public, Citizens, Mobile-Users, Viewers, Future-purchasers, Users, End-users, Students, Job-seekers, Enjoyers, Visitors, Frequent-visitors, Persons, Individuals, Frequenter, Obtainers, Receivers, Assignees, Recipients, Travelers, Tourists, Guys, Persons, Men and Women, Spectators, Technicians, Staff, Workers, Recruiters, Newcomers, Representatives, Dealers, Distributors, Followers, Shareholders, Investors, Bondholders, Shareowners, Financiers, Bankers, Participants, Associates, Assistants, Colleagues, Contributors, Helpers, Partakers, Party, Sharers, Supporters, Admirers, Devotees, Groupies, Enthusiasts and many more.
            [mod_date] => 1467736200
        )

)
```

I did my research for this and found plenty of functions, from which I have tried this:

```
 function arrayRecursiveDiff($aArray1, $aArray2) { 
    $aReturn = array(); 

    foreach ($aArray1 as $mKey => $mValue) { 
        if (array_key_exists($mKey, $aArray2)) { 
            if (is_array($mValue)) { 
                $aRecursiveDiff = arrayRecursiveDiff($mValue, $aArray2[$mKey]); 
                if (count($aRecursiveDiff)) { $aReturn[$mKey] = $aRecursiveDiff; } 
            } else { 
                if ($mValue != $aArray2[$mKey]) { 
                    $aReturn[$mKey] = $mValue; 
                } 
            } 
        } else { 
            $aReturn[$mKey] = $mValue; 
        } 
    } 

    return $aReturn; 
} 

$arr1 = arrayRecursiveDiff($newentry,$oldentry);
```

But it is only showing me the new entry without any comparison. Hope I have explained my problem well enough.

Comment: Which attributes are you expecting to be different, `b_discription` only or the whole object? [This class provides a diff comparison](http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/diff-implementation/) like you would encounter with source code revision systems.

Comment: i want to compare whole array values so i can highlight the changes in new one

Comment: Yes something like that you show in the link

Comment: but how do i compare array values using this @mulquin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gathered you're looking at a way to highlight differences in text to see the differences between the descriptions. From there, may I suggest that you limit the diff function to just `b_discription` as the other attributes don't appear to be within the scope of what you need. Do you expect `business_logo`, `business_name` or `mod_date` to be changed? Regardless, the following function can be run over all attributes in your object if they can be converted to a string.

**[simplediff](https://github.com/paulgb/simplediff/blob/master/php/simplediff.php)** is an excellent script that finds the difference between two strings, including:

- Exists in A and not B (Deletion)
- Exists in B and not A (Insertion)

```php
<?php
/*
    Paul's Simple Diff Algorithm v 0.1
    (C) Paul Butler 2007 <http://www.paulbutler.org/>
    May be used and distributed under the zlib/libpng license.
*/
function diff($old, $new){
    $matrix = array();
    $maxlen = 0;
    foreach($old as $oindex => $ovalue){
        $nkeys = array_keys($new, $ovalue);
        foreach($nkeys as $nindex){
            $matrix[$oindex][$nindex] = isset($matrix[$oindex - 1][$nindex - 1]) ?
                $matrix[$oindex - 1][$nindex - 1] + 1 : 1;
            if($matrix[$oindex][$nindex] > $maxlen){
                $maxlen = $matrix[$oindex][$nindex];
                $omax = $oindex + 1 - $maxlen;
                $nmax = $nindex + 1 - $maxlen;
            }
        }   
    }
    if($maxlen == 0) return array(array('d'=>$old, 'i'=>$new));
    return array_merge(
        diff(array_slice($old, 0, $omax), array_slice($new, 0, $nmax)),
        array_slice($new, $nmax, $maxlen),
        diff(array_slice($old, $omax + $maxlen), array_slice($new, $nmax + $maxlen)));
}
function htmlDiff($old, $new){
    $ret = '';
    $diff = diff(preg_split("/[\s]+/", $old), preg_split("/[\s]+/", $new));
    foreach($diff as $k){
        if(is_array($k))
            $ret .= (!empty($k['d'])?"<del>".implode(' ',$k['d'])."</del> ":'').
                (!empty($k['i'])?"<ins>".implode(' ',$k['i'])."</ins> ":'');
        else $ret .= $k . ' ';
    }
    return $ret;
}

$old = "We smsfactory are world's leading SMS messaging provider offering remarakable and reliable SMS Text and Voice messaging globally through almost all-networks of mobile phones successfully. You may contact-us anytime for making any query. Our Services are very useful economically as well as eco-friendly";

$new = "We smsfactory are world's leading SMS messaging provider offering remarakable and reliable SMS Text and Voice messaging globally through almost all-networks of mobile phones successfully. You may contact-us anytime for making any query. Our Services are very useful economically as well as eco-friendly, which enables you to send simultaneous bulk sms to your targeted Customers, Regular-Customers, Buyers, Shoppers, Fans, Regular-shoppers, Clients, Clientele, Members, Managers, Supervisors, Fieldworkers, Graduates, Post graduates, Technicians, Public, Citizens, Mobile-Users, Viewers, Future-purchasers, Users, End-users, Students, Job-seekers, Enjoyers, Visitors, Frequent-visitors, Persons, Individuals, Frequenter, Obtainers, Receivers, Assignees, Recipients, Travelers, Tourists, Guys, Persons, Men and Women, Spectators, Technicians, Staff, Workers, Recruiters, Newcomers, Representatives, Dealers, Distributors, Followers, Shareholders, Investors, Bondholders, Shareowners, Financiers, Bankers, Participants, Associates, Assistants, Colleagues, Contributors, Helpers, Partakers, Party, Sharers, Supporters, Admirers, Devotees, Groupies, Enthusiasts and many more.";

?>
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <style>
        .container {
            width: 50%;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 16px;
        }

        del {
            background-color: #FFAB91;
            color: ;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        ins {
            background-color: #C5E1A5;
            color: ;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <?php echo htmlDiff($old, $new); ?>
    </div>  
</body>
</head>
```

**Working Example: https://3v4l.org/uU0dv**

Comment: Well thanks a lot buddy this script is awesome it saves my lots of time thanks :)

Comment: hi @mulquin can you please tell me, is it compare the `html` tags too?