# How to find a different array between the two multidimentional arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

Assume that I have two multidimensional arrays as follows:

**Multidimensional array 1**:

```
$newArray = Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 45521
        [1] => Clothing
        [2] =>  Percent discount
        [3] =>  Get 15% off With Code ABCD15
        [4] =>  2020-05-18
        [5] => 2020-05-31
        [6] => ABCD15
        [7] =>  https://domain[dot]com/AYuANDEqU40
        [8] => Boutique
        [9] => Germany 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 45516
        [1] => Apparel
        [2] =>  Percentage Off
        [3] =>  15% off With Code ABCD15
        [4] =>  2020-05-18
        [5] => 2020-05-31
        [6] => ABCD15
        [7] =>  https://domain[dot]com/AYuANDEqU40
        [8] => Boutique
        [9] => Australia 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 45672
        [1] => Food & Drink
        [2] =>  Free Shipping
        [3] =>  Summer Collection Now. Shop Now!
        [4] =>  2020-05-17
        [5] => 2020-08-01
        [6] => N/A
        [7] =>  https://domain[dot]com/AYuANDEqU40761312
        [8] => Fancy
        [9] => US 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 45866
        [1] => Food & Drink
        [2] =>  Percentage off
        [3] =>  20% Off
        [4] =>  2020-05-17
        [5] => 2026-05-15
        [6] => OFF20
        [7] =>  https://domain[dot]com/AYuANDEqU40780908
        [8] => Biata
        [9] => US 
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 45524
        [1] => Health & Wellness
        [2] =>  Other
        [3] =>  Jet's monthly bottle of probiotics. Try it now!
        [4] =>  2020-05-02
        [5] => 2026-05-01
        [6] => N/A
        [7] =>  https://domain[dot]com/AYuANDEqU40758409
        [8] => Jet
        [9] => US 
    )
)
[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 45524
        [1] => Health & Wellness
        [2] =>  Other
        [3] =>  Jet seasonal probiotics.  No hidden cost.
        [4] =>  2020-05-02
        [5] => 2026-05-01
        [6] => N/A
        [7] =>  https://domain[dot]com/AYuANDEqU40758408
        [8] => Jet
        [9] => US 
    )
```

**Multidimension array 2**:

```
$oldArray = Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 45521
        [1] => Clothing's
        [2] =>  Percent discount
        [3] =>  Get 15% off With Code ABCD15
        [4] =>  2020-05-18
        [5] => 2020-05-31
        [6] => ABCD15
        [7] =>  https://domain[dot]com/AYuANDEqU40
        [8] => Boutique
        [9] => Germany 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 45516
        [1] => Apparel
        [2] =>  Percentage Off
        [3] =>  15% off With Code ABCD15
        [4] =>  2020-05-18
        [5] => 2020-05-31
        [6] => ABCD15
        [7] =>  https://domain[dot]com/AYuANDEqU40
        [8] => Boutique
        [9] => Australia 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 45672
        [1] => Food & Drink
        [2] =>  Free Shipping
        [3] =>  Summer Collection Now. Shop Now!
        [4] =>  2020-05-17
        [5] => 2020-08-01
        [6] => N/A
        [7] =>  https://domain[dot]com/AYuANDEqU40761312
        [8] => Fancy
        [9] => US 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 45866
        [1] => Food & Drink
        [2] =>  Percentage off
        [3] =>  20% Off
        [4] =>  2020-05-17
        [5] => 2026-05-15
        [6] => OFF20
        [7] =>  https://domain[dot]com/AYuANDEqU40780908
        [8] => Biata
        [9] => US 
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 45706
        [1] => Electronic Equipment
        [2] =>  Percentage off
        [3] =>  40% Off-Set Under $200!
        [4] =>  2020-05-17
        [5] => 2026-05-15
        [6] => N/A
        [7] =>  https://domain[dot]com/AYuANDEqU40768379
        [8] => GVM
        [9] => US 
    )
)
```

You can easily see that the `$newArray` has one different `array([4])` from the `$oldArray`, and one new `array([5])` to the `$oldArray`, and **one different key=value pair `like [1] => Clothing's` from the $oldArray**

What i am expecting is to compare the `$newArray` with the `$oldArray` to get the different `array([4])` and the new one `array([5])` in the `$newArray` only.

I have searched for these links:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php
and 
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_diff_assoc.asp
but they do not help.

Then I've searched for the function in this link:
[Compare two different multidimentional arrays and highlight the changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38202085/compare-two-different-multidimentional-arrays-and-highlight-the-changes)

**The function:**

```
function arrayRecursiveDiff($aArray1, $aArray2) { 
$aReturn = array(); 

foreach ($aArray1 as $mKey => $mValue) { 
    if (array_key_exists($mKey, $aArray2)) { 
        if (is_array($mValue)) { 
            $aRecursiveDiff = arrayRecursiveDiff($mValue, $aArray2[$mKey]); 
            if (count($aRecursiveDiff)) { $aReturn[$mKey] = $aRecursiveDiff; 
        } 
    } else { 
        if ($mValue != $aArray2[$mKey]) { 
            $aReturn[$mKey] = $mValue; 
        } 
    } 
    } else { 
        $aReturn[$mKey] = $mValue; 
    } 
} 

return $aReturn; 
} 

$arr1 = arrayRecursiveDiff($newentry,$oldentry);
```

It filters and shows me both the **COMPLETE new arrays** from the `$newArray` and the **new arrays** from the `$newArray` with only the *key=value pairs* that are different from the `$oldArray`.

Yes and again, what i am expecting is to compare the `$newArray` with the `$oldArray` to get:

1/ The COMPLETE different array like `array([4])` from the `$newArray`.
2/ The new array like `array([5])` from the `$newArray`.
3/ The arrays from the `$newArray` of which one of the *key=value* pairs is different from that of the `$oldArray`, but it must print all 9 *key=value* pairs of that array, which is the array[0] in this example. I don't want to get the new arrays from `$newArray` with the output of ONLY the updated *key=value* pairs.

Sorry for a long post with wordy explanation, but I have no choice.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: The solution debpends on what can differ between the arrays. Could a new entry be between two old entries? How do you distinguish a new entry from an old entry with new values? Is the order of the entries always the same?

Comment: _The solution debpends on what can differ between the arrays_ => I would like to get the arrays from the `$newArray` variable of which one of their `key=value` pairs is different from that of the arrays from  the `$oleArray` variable.

Comment: _Could a new entry be between two old entries?_=> Yes, it could be.

Comment: _How do you distinguish a new entry from an old entry with new values?_ => It should be distinguished by any value among the 9 ones. One value can be considered as a string.

Comment: _Is the order of the entries always the same?_ => The new array from the $newArray should be contrasted against each and every array in the `$oldArray` variable before deciding if it is the new one or not.

Comment: This looks like a good approach to learn some test-driven development. Craft simple example cases, write a test case for it, and then implement the diff algorithm. This might work out much better than using somehing existing and adapt it by hand until you think it fits your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
$a1=array(1,2,3);
$a2=array(1,2,4);

$i =0;
$diff_Value = ''; 
foreach( $a1 as $val )
{
    if($a2[$i]!=$val){
        $diff_Value.= $val.','.$a2[$i];
    }
    $i =$i+1;
}


echo $diff_Value;
```